# Rescue my elasticsearch cluster when one master down and another master node' id is not correct

Tags: elasticsearch

## Background:

1. There is an old Elasticsearch cluster has 3 master nodes, minimum nodes are 2
2. One server died, cannot recover very soon.
3. The left two nodes cannot elect master node, they are complaining:

```
master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires at least 2 nodes 
with ids from [DnW5_lRBRhinokBu542Mvw, LSS3ms9gSlmisxOgLmQZXw, nE5cqi4OQKui5VSWz1hW7g], 
have discovered [{dc17-esmaster-04}{LSS3ms9gSlmisxOgLmQZXw}{GyJYhRLLTB-SC66nu3d__w}....
```

```
master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires at least 2 nodes 
with ids from [DnW5_lRBRhinokBu542Mvw, LSS3ms9gSlmisxOgLmQZXw, nE5cqi4OQKui5VSWz1hW7g], 
have discovered [{dc17-esmaster-01}{rxzeJiTHQ2OlQK8iLAj-VQ}{ICKLYhcsSHy2hDajZs0cPw}{
```

## My understanding:

1. usually, one master node down has no impacting, 2 nodes should work
2. However, in my case, one of master node's ID is not in array: [DnW5_lRBRhinokBu542Mvw, LSS3ms9gSlmisxOgLmQZXw, nE5cqi4OQKui5VSWz1hW7g], as the second log above showing, that node's ID is rxzeJiTHQ2OlQK8iLAj-VQ.
3. So, I guess the truth is node 1 never join cluster successfully before, only another two nodes working, today, one node died, so, whole cluster crash.

## How to solve it? I think there are two options:

1. modify that node's ID to one id from that array, but I don't know how to do it, node is was generated automatically...
2. let ES cluster forget this array [DnW5_lRBRhinokBu542Mvw, LSS3ms9gSlmisxOgLmQZXw, nE5cqi4OQKui5VSWz1hW7g] and re-discovery the cluster, I know it is stored in global-xx.st file, but it is a binary file, cannot edit at all, and I am afraid to break data integrity..

Maybe there is 3rd option:

1. Add two more master nodes, make whole cluster with 5 nodes, so, there are 3 nodes live, cluster can work, then remove two bad nodes later..

Please give me some suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found truth..

There were 4 master nodes before, 01 was excluded automatically because it cannot have even number nodes to elect.

Then, 03 was removed by someone for hardware issue, and he/she didn't put 01 back to elect clsuter..

when 02 down, there is only one node active, but 01 cannot elect...

Issue fixed.